# Cannot change ViewModel name, no parameterless constructor for MVVM viewmodel in Xamarin UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am currently making a Xamarin UWP app that uses MVVM for its interfaces. I am targeting a platform version of 10.0.19041.0 with minimum of 10.0.17763.0. Target framework is netstandard 2.0. I am on Windows 10.

I am running into errors trying to change the name of a viewmodel. It works perfectly when the viewmodel in question has its default name, but crashes with the parameterless constructor error when I change the name.

Here is the working setup that does not crash. I have a viewmodel class named DeviceListViewModel. Here is the code for it including its constructor with parameters:

```
public class DeviceListViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private readonly IBluetoothLE _bluetoothLe;
    private readonly IUserDialogs _userDialogs;
    private readonly ISettings _settings;
    ...
    public DeviceListViewModel(IBluetoothLE bluetoothLe, IAdapter adapter, IUserDialogs userDialogs, ISettings settings, IPermissions permissions) : base(adapter) {
        _bluetoothLe = bluetoothLe;
        _userDialogs = userDialogs;
        _settings = settings;

        _bluetoothLe.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
        Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += OnDeviceDiscovered;
        Adapter.ScanTimeoutElapsed += Adapter_ScanTimeoutElapsed;
        Adapter.DeviceDisconnected += OnDeviceDisconnected;
        Adapter.DeviceConnectionLost += OnDeviceConnectionLost;

        BleMvxApplication._reader1.DisconnectAsync();
    }
    ...
 }
```

The variable 'Adapter' is inheried from the BaseViewModel class as a protected variable, initialized like this within the BaseViewModel class:

```
protected readonly IAdapter Adapter;
```

In the entire codebase outside of the initialization shown above, there is only **one** spot where the DeviceListViewModel is used. It is called in a ShowViewModel function call in another file:

```
void OnConnectButtonClicked() {
    ...
    ShowViewModel<DeviceListViewModel>(new MvxBundle());
    ...
}
```

The errors occurs when I try to change the name DeviceListViewModel. In the three places in the entire codebase that the class name appears, if any changes are made to it I get the parameterless constructor error.

I have attempted to make one, but there are some issues there. The class requires parameters to function normally, and attempting to make one without parameters has errors. Here simple examples:

```
public DeviceListViewModel() {} // fails since it does not inherit from BaseViewModelClass

public DeviceListViewModel() : base(adapter) {} // adapter does not exist in current context

public DeviceListViewModel() : base(Adapter) {} // An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BaseViewModel.Adapter'
```

Regardless of these attempts to create a parameterless constructor, I need the variables initialized like _bluetoothLe and _userDialogs since they are called in other parts of the code.

So, to reiterate, the issue is that changing the class name causes it to fail. Changing the three times 'DeviceListViewModel' shows up to something like 'DeviceListViewModel1' will cause the code to fail and a parameterless constructor error to occur. I am trying to change the name since I would like to make other versions of this class with different names but even keeping everything else the same and just changing the name stops the class from functioning.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `partial` declared `DeviceListViewModel` somewhere with a parameterless ctor and did not rename that part?

Comment: @fvetsch Just checked, and unfortunately there are no partials declared anywhere for DeviceListViewModel, BaseViewModel, or any methods, etc. related to them. The viewmodels in this codebase are entirely without partials, it appears.

Comment: “Uses MVVM” means what, exactly?  Are you using a specific MVVM library?

Comment: It broke because the name change means VM not automatically found. I see `MvxBundle`, so I infer this is `mvvmcross`. Read their docs about how to declare the association between a view and a viewmodel, when the names don't fit the pattern. Terms to search for: `OnViewModelSet`, `CreateBindingSet`. (I infer your view is named `DeviceListView`; mvx appends `Model`, finds `DeviceListViewModel` automatically.) NOTE: The constructor problem is SPECIFIC to the mvvm library you are using; you need to find out how that library handles the need for constructor parameters.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you for this comment. this allowed me to find that there were variables/classes associated with the name 'DeviceList' that were no longer functioning once I renamed the DeviceList viewmodel. I have since redone my naming convention and it runs perfectly. I have posted an answer to my own question that outlines this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution thanks to @ToolmakerSteve's comment on the post.

In the XAML associated with my DeviceListViewModel, there were variables/xaml/xaml.cs files that depended on the name 'DeviceList'. Since I was changing the viewmodel to DeviceListViewModel, it was breaking the naming convention that the mvvmcross and view/viewmodel connection uses.

It now works by renaming my viewmodel instead to DeviceList1ViewModel and all the DeviceList variables to DeviceList1.

In summary, even though I was changing every instance of my viewmodel 'DeviceListViewModel', there were other functions of code associated with the 'DeviceList' that make my ViewModel crash when it was renamed. Check the associated regions if you have a similar issue.